# Having trouble making page change work when set from url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, odata, angular-ui

I'm building an app using AngularJS and OData Controller. I created the pagination using Angular-ui.

```
<div class="table" ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
   <!-- bunch of data to be shown here - The table stuff --> 
    <uib-pagination class="pagination" 
     total-items="ctrl.totalItems"
     items-per-page="10"
     max-size="10"
     rotate="false"
     boundary-links="true"
     ng-model="ctrl.currentPage"
     ng-change="ctrl.pageChanged(ctrl.currentPage)">
    </uib-pagination>
</div>
```

This works perfect. What happened was when user goes to the next page, select a table for detail view, then click 'Done' or 'Cancel' or whatever button to get out of the detail view to the table view, the view is set back to first page instead of taking them back to whatever page they were before.

So, what I ended up doing, is creating a state using ui-router. 
Here's the ui-router state

```
.state('Claims', {
                url: '/Claims?page',
                templateUrl: baseUrl + 'Scripts/App/Views/Template/denied/denied-claims-table.html',
                params: {
                    page: {
                        value: '0',
                        squash: true
                    }
                }
            })

            .state('Detail', {
                url: '/Claims?page&id/detail',
                templateUrl: baseUrl + 'Scripts/App/Views/Template/denied/denied-claims-details-panel.html',
                params: {
                    page: {
                        value: '0',
                        squash: true
                    },
                    id: {
                        value: '0',
                        squash: true
                    }
                }
            })
```

And here's my controller:

```
deniedClaimsApp.controller('DeniedClaimsController', [
    '$scope',
    '$state',
    '$stateParams',
    'DeniedClaimsService',
    'SharedDataService',
    function ($scope, $state, $stateParams, DeniedClaimsService, SharedDataService) {

        var vm = this;
        var claimBK = {};
        vm.claims = {};
        vm.totalItems;        
        vm.numPages = 10;

        vm.currentPage = parseInt($stateParams.page, 10) || 1;

        console.log('Current Page: ' + $stateParams.page);
        activate();

        SharedDataService.registerObserver(activate);

        function activate() {

            $scope.$emit('LOAD');

            vm.isCollapsed = true;
            console.log("Page set to : " + vm.currentPage);

            //vm.currentPage = DeniedClaimsService.getCurrentPage();
            vm.currentPage = $stateParams.page;
            vm.claims = DeniedClaimsService.getClaims(vm.currentPage);
            angular.copy(vm.claims, claimBK);

            resolve();
            $state.go('.', { page: vm.currentPage }, { notify: false });
        }



        function resolve() {
            vm.currentPage = $stateParams.page; //adding this didn't help either
            console.log("Resolve: " + vm.currentPage);
            vm.claims.$promise.then(function (data) {
                vm.totalItems = data.count;
                $scope.$emit('UNLOAD');
            });
        }

       vm.pageChanged = function (page) {

/*
 This is where page is always 1. For some reason, when the page number is changed from the url, it raises the page change event, but the ng-model in uib-pagination doesn't change to the page set in the url. It always stays 1 and changes the page back to the first page
*/
            $scope.$emit('LOAD');

            //vm.currentPage = $stateParams.page;
            console.log("New page: " + vm.currentPage);
            console.log('changing page');
            vm.claims = DeniedClaimsService.pageChanged(vm.currentPage);
            vm.claims.$promise.then(function (data) {

                $scope.$emit('UNLOAD');
            });
            console.log("Changing State to: " + vm.currentPage);
            $state.go('.', { page: vm.currentPage }, { notify: false });
            console.log("Changing pagination: " + vm.currentPage);
            //vm.currentPage = $stateParams.page;

        }
```

So, the controller is only there to change the page, and a couple other things that is not shown here for brevity. When I change the page using the 'Next' or 'Prev' buttons, the page changes fine. But when I change the page from the url and obtain the page from `$stateParams.page`, it changes the page back to first page no matter which page I was in. I thought it had something to do with the page change event raised when using ng-change. So, I changed `uib-pagination` `ng-change` to `ng-click="ctrl.pageChanged(ctrl.currentPage)`. Doing this did change the page when the page number is set in the url as `/Claims?page=5`then it'd take me to page 5, but it didn't change the `ng-model` in `uib-pagination`. That remained 1 even though the table is displaying data for page 5. So, after changing to page 5 from the url, and if I change the page by clicking 'Next', it would take me to page 2 instead of page 6. What am I doing wrong? Why is that model not changing with the change in value for the same model?